# Display Suite Custom Wrappers and Custom Classes Tabs Not Appearing in Manage Display

Tags: 8, theming, display-suite

I am using Display Suite layouts for some of my pages. I want to add in some custom classes for the regions. However, the custom classes and custom wrappers tabs are not appearing on the Manage Display screen for my view modes. I am able to add custom classes on the Display Suite Custom Classes screen, but cannot apply them to the display, as the tabs are not there.

Am I missing something? I have seen videos where they appear for other users so don't know why they are not appearing for me.

Below is a screenshot showing the missing tabs.

[image: Missing tabs]

I want to basically target the view mode as a class on the page. At the moment, it is only inserting the layout I have selected as a class, so if I am using the same layout for different view modes I can't differentiate between them if they are for the same content type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possibilities come to mind.

1) Have you saved since you selected "One Column" as the layout? The configuration options change once you select something other than -None-

or

2) Have you checked that you have the correct Display Suite permissions? Namely, 'Administer classes' and 'Administer fields'

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I have saved it and I checked the permissions as well and the tabs are not showing. I think I might need to put a request in the module issue queue.

Comment: It was my mistake. I didn't realise Drupal 8 included its own native layouts in the layout dropdown and I had selected the Drupal One Column Layout not the Display Suite One Column Layout.

Comment: Well I have the same problem. I am using indeed layouts from Display Suite and I checked the permissions and they are fine, but Custom wrappers tab doesn't show up. Any other ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Forget it! I deleted the display, recreated it and suddenly the option was there... I also installed in the mean time the 'Display Suite Extras' module, not sure this was the actual solution, but worth to give it a try.